# On clicking a button the image on canvas goes out of canvas Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Hi i am newbie to reactjs. When i take a screenshot of webgl, the captured screenshot is put in preview. But then the webgl on canvas from where i took the screenshot, appears bulged. I suppose its because the webgl which is small is trying to fit a canvas which is larger than this.

Below is the screenshot method to capture webgl:

```
window.screenshot = function(width, height) {
const width1 = gl_active.canvas.width;
const height1 = gl_active.canvas.height;

gl_active.canvas.width = width;
gl_active.canvas.height = height;

GL_draw(gl_active);
const buffer = get_buffer();

let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//gl has reverse y-axis, flip vertically
const flipped_buffer = [],
    channels = 4;   //RGBA
for (let i = buffer.length - width * channels; i >= 0; i -= width * channels) {
    for (let e = 0; e < width * channels; e++) {
        flipped_buffer.push(buffer[i + e]);
    }
}
let imageData = ctx.createImageData(width, height);
imageData.data.set(flipped_buffer);
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
return canvas.toDataURL();
```

};

I call the screenshot method as below
preview = screenshot(300, 300);

Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Please add relevant code. If possible a codepen or jsfiddle link.

Comment: In order to help you, create a [Minimal,Complete and Verifiable example(https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A codepen or jsfiddle is also nice